# Convert weighted direct cyclic graph to equivalent acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a cyclic weighted directed graph and the goal is to remove the cycle present in the path.

eg: the paths are as below,

```
from | to | weight
------------------
a    -> b | 0.5
a    -> c | 0.5
c    -> e | 1
b    -> d | 1
d    -> a | 0.25
d    -> f | 0.75
```

the cycle in the graph is introduced by the path d -> a. Can anyone suggest an algorithm to remove the cycle d -> a by adjusting the weights of the other nodes. The resulting acyclic graph to be equivalent in terms of passing on the weights to the end nodes e, f.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: I think maximum-flow\minimum-cut can do the trick

Comment: What are you going to do with your acyclic Markov chain? What you're asking for (cycle removal while preserving intermediate nodes) isn't well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment to David's answer and from the weights of the graph, it looks to me like the weights are probabilities to move from one node to the other (or percentage of a unit that moves from on node to another, either way the math is the same). If so, this can be modeled as a [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), and more specifically as an [absorbing Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain). But first, we need to add two paths to fit the formal definition:

```
e -> e | 1.0
f -> f | 1.0
```

I'm not sure if you need a general algorithm for multiple graphs similar to this one or this is the only graph you need to solve. I'll give an overview of the math involved for this particular graph, and hopefully you can generalize it into an algorithm if you need it.

<sub>*The arithmetic is pretty cumbersome, follow along on the [absorbing Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) link.*</sub>

First, we need the adjacency matrix, more commonly called the *state transition matrix* when dealing with Markov chains:

```
  |  a     b     c     d  |  e     f
--+-----------------------+------------
a |  0     0.5   0.5   0  |  0     0
b |  0     0     0     1  |  0     0
c |  0     0     0     0  |  1     0
d |  0.25  0     0     0  |  0     0.75
--+-----------------------+------------
e |  0     0     0     0  |  1     0
f |  0     0     0     0  |  0     1
```

The top left portion of the matrix are the transitions between the *transient* (non-ending) states (symbolized by *Q*), the bottom right are the *absorbing* states. The top right will be symbolized by *R*.

The *fundamental matrix*, is calculated as *N* = (*I* - *Q*)<sup>-1</sup>. While the *absorbing probabilities* (i.e. given infinite time, the percentage that will end up in each of the absorbing states) is given as *B* = *NR*. Using my best ASCII matrices, the numbers for this graph are:

```
         +-          -+             +-    -+  
         | 8  4  4  4 |             | 4  3 |
         | 2  8  1  8 |             | 1  6 |
N = (1/7)| 0  0  7  0 |    B = (1/7)| 7  0 |
         | 2  1  1  8 |             | 1  6 |
         +-          -+             +-    -+
```

The top row of the *B* matrix is read, starting from state a, there's a 4/7 (approx. 0.5714) chance of ending up in state e, and a 3/7 (approx. 0.4286) chance of ending up in state f. You can ignore the other three rows, since those are the probabilities when starting in states b, c, and d.

Therefore if you want an equivalent graph where the end chance of ending up in states e and f are the same, but without the cycle, you can remove the d -> a path, and use the following weights:

```
a -> b | 0.4286
a -> c | 0.5714
```

Comment: The solution above sounds fine and it gives the effective percentage/probability from starting node to the end node. But I need the intermediate probability as well like A -> B, A -> C. In the sample case, the path was small so we can see what might be the percentage from A -> B. But in real use-case, the path is long and so it is not straight forward.

Comment: @Vivek Could you give more example graphs then? Its hard to know how general the algorithm needs to be. I'm thinking it might be possible to start from the end nodes, and work backwards to find cycles then applying the above math on portions of the graph at a time.

Comment: In particular, we would need to know more about the cycles. Can they be nested (like a larger cycle "going around" a smaller one)? Are they 3-cycles or greater? In particular its easy to imagine a graph where the nodes form a sort of large circle, and there's one end node branching off the circle. The problem seems ill-defined for such edge case graphs. What would be done in such a case, or would cases like these not exist?

Comment: The real case, there are nested cycles and the total number of nodes is around 3000. At present, I am removing one cycle at a time (using the algorithm I mentioned in the other answer) and re-processing. But this is taking a lot of processing time. So I wanted to know if there is any simpler algorithm to solve it.

Comment: How about some edge case graphs though? For example assume a is the starting node, f and g are end nodes. We have the following paths (ab means a -> b): ab, bc, cd, de, ea, be, cf, dg. ab and ea have weight 1.0, bc has weight 0.4, be has weight 0.6 and the rest have weights of 0.5. This graph I just defined has two cycles and it's not entirely obvious which paths to remove to make it acyclic.

Answer (score 4):

Sleator–Tarjan call this the acyclic flow problem and describe an O(m log n)-time solution on page 389 of their [first paper on dynamic trees](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sleator/papers/dynamic-trees.pdf). If you don't need the fastest algorithm, repeatedly use depth-first search to find one flow cycle and then send in reverse the minimum amount of flow that cancels one or more arcs.

On your graph:

```
a    -> b | 0.5
a    -> c | 0.5
c    -> e | 1
b    -> d | 1
d    -> a | 0.25
d    -> f | 0.75
```

DFS finds a cycle `a -0.5> b -1> d -0.25> a`. Send `-0.25` on that same cycle.

```
a    -> b | 0.5 - 0.25 = 0.25
a    -> c | 0.5
c    -> e | 1
b    -> d | 1 - 0.25 = 0.75
d    -> f | 0.75
```

We delete

```
d    -> a | 0.25 - 0.25 = 0
```

The flow is acyclic, so we stop.

Comment: I think we should reverse 0.125 on the same cycle as only 0.125 is transferred from d -> a.

Comment: @Vivek Where did the number 0.125 come from?

Comment: As per your logic, after removing the cycle, the graph turns to 
a->b:0.25, a->c:0.5, c->e:1. Lets try passing 1 unit of content from a to other nodes. so 'a' would transfer 0.5 of the content to b and 0.5 of the content to c. Then c would transfer 0.125 back to a and 0.375 to e. So the net flowing back to a is 0.125 in the path.

Comment: @VivekViswanathan: in this example, it converges to the same result. Do you have prove it won't converge in general?